# What does reduction of structure group of principal bundle say?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, big-list, principal-bundles

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}\DeclareMathOperator\SO{SO}$Let $G$ be a Lie group and $\pi:P\rightarrow M$ be a principal $G$ bundle.

The notion of reduction of structure group is standard but I will recall here in case someone needs it.

Let $f:P(M,G)\rightarrow P'(M',G')$ be a morphism of principal bundles such that $f:P\rightarrow P'$ is an embedding and $f:G\rightarrow G'$ is a monomorphism. If $M=M'$ and the induced map $f:M\rightarrow M'$ is identity map, we call $P(M,G)$ to be reduced bundle for $P'(M,G').$

Given a principal bundle $P’(M’,G’)$ and a Lie subgroup $G$ of $G’,$ we say the structure group $G’$ is reduced to $G$ if there is a reduced bundle $P(M,G).$

Reduction of structure group says something interesting about manifolds involving it. For example,

- A manifold  **admits an almost-complex structure** if the frame bundle on the manifold, whose fibers are $\GL(2n,\mathbb{R})$, can be reduced to the group $\GL(n,\mathbb{C})\subset \GL(2n,\mathbb{R})$.
- A manifold is **orientable** if and only if its frame bundle can be reduced to the special orthogonal group, $\SO(n,\mathbb{R})\subset \GL(n,\mathbb{R})$.

I am interested in knowing similar results about the reduction of structure group. Please add references (if possible, a sketch of the proof) for the results you quote here. One result in one answer please.

Comment: Results that are not very standard are most welcome. If you use some result in your paper that has something to do with reduction of structure group, please consider adding that as an answer.

Comment: Your understanding of proof of any of the above three results I have mentioned in your own words is also most welcome :)

Comment: A spin structure is not really a reduction...

Comment: @PaulReynolds https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_bundle#Reduction_of_the_structure_group says that.. I do not know the proof.. I would like to know if this is not the case..

Comment: @PaulReynolds are you saying this because $\mathrm{Spin_n}$ is not a subgroup of $\mathrm O_n$? The definition of "reduction of structure group" that I learned involved a map $\rho\colon G\to\mathrm O_n$, not just subgroups, but maybe there are different definitions out there.

Comment: Sternberg ([1964](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=193578), Chap. VII) starts with many examples, pp. 310–313: 1) complete parallelisms 2) [distributions](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(differential_geometry)) 3) Riemannian metrics 4) conformal structures 5) [almost symplectic structures](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_symplectic_manifold) 6) almost complex structures 7) volume forms 8) orientations.

Comment: @ArunDebray, yes, that's all I'm saying, and I agree it's in the same family of things. The OP's definition doesn't include spin structures in its current form.

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler Thanks for the reference.. I will see...

Comment: @ArunDebray I am little confused now.. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_bundle#Use_of_the_notion says it consider only subgroups.. I did not bother to check (apologies) if Spin group is subrgoup or SO(n) or not.. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_group says it is not.. I think wikipedia is following your notation (i.e.,$G\rightarrow H$ is only a morphism of Lie groups) even if it says otherwise..

Comment: @PaulReynolds I see. I guess I learned a nonstandard definition. Sorry about that.

Comment: @PaulReynolds I have removed that to come out of that confusion..

Comment: @Arun I would call that a lift of the structure group, but I think if you said "reduction of structure group to Spin(n)" it would probably cause minimal confusion.

Comment: You have it backwards: $P'=P \times_G G'$ is automatically determined from $P$, so it is actually $P$ that is the reduction of structure group of $P'$.

Comment: Given _any_ group homomorphism $\phi\colon H\to G$ and a principal $G$-bundle $P\to M$ (or even a $G$-fibre bundle), one can ask for the existence of a principal $H$-bundle $Q\to M$ such that $P \simeq Q\times_H G$, where $H$ acts on $G$ via $\phi$. This is equivalent to asking if the Čech cocycle arising from the transition functions for $P$ is in the image of $H^1(M,H) \to H^1(M,G)$. There are a large number of other equivalent formalisations of this. For the fibre bundle case, the version using transition functions is the one that makes immediate sense.

Comment: @BenMcKay yes.. I will correct it.. typo.. Thank you :)

Comment: @DavidRoberts Yes, I am familiar with that definition also.. Closest to what you said is is in Kobayashi Proposition 5.3..

Answer (score 6):

Let $G$ be a topological group and $M$ be a smooth manifold. Then, a reduction of the structure group of the frame bundle from $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb R)$ to $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb R)\times G$ is equivalent data to a principal $G$-bundle $Q\to M$.

Here's a proof sketch: if $H$ and $H'$ are groups, an $(H\times H')$-torsor is the same thing as a product of an $H$-torsor and an $H'$-torsor. So the fiber of the principal $(\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb R)\times G)$-bundle we obtained from the frame bundle at some $x\in M$ is a product of a $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb R)$-torsor $P_x$ and a $G$-torsor $Q_x$, and $P_x$ is the $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb R)$ of bases of $T_xM$. Since $Q_x$ varies smoothly, it defines a principal $G$-bundle $Q\to M$.

Comment: I am not familiar with this definition of reduction of structure group where we are not considering injective morphism of groups... Are you saying there is some natural map $GL_n(\mathbb{R})\times G\rightarrow GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ with which we are thinking of structure group reduction?? I am not able to think of any natural map... I see there is a map $GL_n(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow GL_n(\mathbb{R})\times G$ that sends $A$ to $(A,1)$...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik right, the definition of "reduction of the structure group" that I learned is not quite the one on Wikipedia; it allows for noninjective maps. In particular, the natural map $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb R)\times G\to\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb R)$ is projection onto the first factor.

Comment: Oh.. I see.. I will try to understand the proof and will respond.

Comment: Why cannot $Q_x$ somehow "entangle" with $P_x$ along the way? Say, if $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb R)$ contains a copy of $G$, in principle it might secretly "swap" with the "external" $G$...

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I think in that case you won't get back the frame bundle when you take the quotient, but rather some other $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb R)$-bundle.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is a very standard fact, but I am surprised nobody wrote it. Please, if I am wrong let me know.

Consider the frame bundle $P'=FM$ of a manifold $M$. In this case, $G'=GL(n)$, and consider $G=O(n)$. The orbit space $P'/G=FM/O(n)$ is also a bundle over $M$.
The fibre $(FM/O(n))_x$ consists of classes of bases of $T_x M$, where the equivalence of bases is given by the existence of an orthogonal transformation between them.

Now, if we have a section $\sigma$ of the bundle $P'/G$, we are assigning, in a smooth way, a class of bases of $T_x M$ to every $x\in M$. We have, then, a new principal bundle $P=\bigsqcup\limits_{x\in M} \{x\}\times \sigma(x)$ with group $O(n)$. It can be shown that is a reduction of the frame bundle.

On the other hand, every class $\sigma(x)$ determines a bilinear form in $T_x M$, indeed, a metric. So we have a Riemannian metric on $M$. On the contrary, a Riemannian metric let us specify a section of $FM/O(n)$, and therefore a principal bundle reduction of the frame bundle.

So the principal bundle reduction, in this case, is giving us the data provided by a Riemannian metric.

By the way, as we know, [every manifold can be equipped with such a metric](https://ajpancollantes.github.io/%E2%99%BE%EF%B8%8F%20CONCEPTS/GEOMETRY/Riemannian%20metric.md.html), and so we always have this kind of principal bundle reduction.

**Added**

One of the examples in the OP's question can be weakened. According to Sternberg **Lectures on differential geometry**:
A $G$-structure on an $n$-dimensional manifold $M$ is defined as a reduction of the frame bundle $FM$ to the group $G$.

Now, let $G = \text{GL}^+ (n; R)$ denotes the group of $n \times n$ matrices with positive determinant over $R$. A manifold $M$ admits a $\text{GL}^+ (n; R)$-structure if and only if it is orientable. This is Example 2.2 in Kobayashi **Transformation groups in differential geometry**.